# IllegalAccessError when running ant.importBuild using gradle 4.1

Tags: gradle, ant

im having trouble importing an old ant build script into gradle.

I have added several ant extensions before importing like this:

```
configurations {
    antdep
}
dependencies {
    // ant script dependencies
    antdep group: 'ant-contrib', name: 'ant-contrib', version: '1.0b3'
    antdep group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.ant', version: '0.7.4.201502262128'
    antdep group: 'org.codehaus.sonar-plugins', name: 'sonar-ant-task', version: '2.2'
    antdep group: 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler', name: 'ecj', '4.3.1'
    antdep group: 'com.oopsconsultancy', name: 'xmltask', version: '1.16'

...
}

def antClassLoader = org.apache.tools.ant.Project.class.classLoader
configurations.antdep.each { File f ->
    antClassLoader.addURL(f.toURI().toURL())
}
```

The code that fails is: `ant.importBuild('src/build.xml')`

We override properties using `<var />` from ant-contrib but otherwise i have no idea on how to debug this.

I get the following stacktrace:

```
14:50:20.789 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
14:50:20.789 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred evaluating project ':utility'.
14:50:20.789 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.google.common.collect.SortedIterables from class com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedSet
14:50:20.790 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:50:20.790 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
14:50:20.791 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':utility'.
14:50:20.791 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:92)
14:50:20.791 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:187)
14:50:20.791 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
14:50:20.791 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:192)
14:50:20.791 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:61)
14:50:20.791 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
14:50:20.791 [ERROR] ... skipped, see pastebin for full stacktrace
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
14:50:20.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
14:50:20.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
14:50:20.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
14:50:20.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
14:50:20.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
14:50:20.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.google.common.collect.SortedIterables from class com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedSet
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2199)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3938)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4821)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4827)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.getTaskClassInfo(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:64)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.process(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:55)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.create(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:51)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.create(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:32)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DependencyAutoWireTaskFactory.create(DependencyAutoWireTaskFactory.java:44)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DependencyAutoWireTaskFactory.create(DependencyAutoWireTaskFactory.java:27)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskInstantiator.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:301)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskInstantiator.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:289)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:116)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultAntBuilder.importBuild(DefaultAntBuilder.java:121)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultAntBuilder.importBuild(DefaultAntBuilder.java:93)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultAntBuilder$importBuild.call(Unknown Source)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at build_50k7lo2jmk8496neix4cqy0gl.run(C:\epj\work\gradle\UTILITY\build.gradle:32)
14:50:20.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
14:50:20.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 93 more
14:50:20.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.google.common.collect.SortedIterables from class com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedSet
14:50:20.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedSet.copyOf(ImmutableSortedSet.java:344)
14:50:20.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedSet.copyOf(ImmutableSortedSet.java:379)
14:50:20.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedSet.copyOf(ImmutableSortedSet.java:291)
14:50:20.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskClassValidator.<init>(TaskClassValidator.java:38)
14:50:20.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassValidatorExtractor.extractValidator(DefaultTaskClassValidatorExtractor.java:136)
14:50:20.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$1.load(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:51)
14:50:20.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$1.load(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:45)
14:50:20.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3524)
14:50:20.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2317)
14:50:20.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2280)
14:50:20.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2195)
14:50:20.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 111 more
```

Full stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/aPkwKj48

if i instead remove `ant.importBuild('src/build.xml')` then i get this stacktrace

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
15:10:00.614 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:10:00.614 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
15:10:00.614 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] tried to access class com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetFromMap from class com.google.common.collect.Sets
15:10:00.615 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:10:00.615 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
15:10:00.630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetFromMap from class com.google.common.collect.Sets
15:10:00.630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.collect.Sets.newSetFromMap(Sets.java:516)
15:10:00.630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.common.collect.Sets.newIdentityHashSet(Sets.java:396)
15:10:00.630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.<init>(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:104)
15:10:00.631 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.<init>(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:87)
15:10:00.631 [ERROR]
```

see full stacktrace here: https://pastebin.com/GKVSuyML